# WiX Upgrade with custom versioning

Tags: wix, windows-installer, versioning, major-upgrade, wixsharp

I got a problem. I want to upgrade my app during installation process, but I run into problem with versioning. I use version number in format e.g. 5.5.789.0, some new version has version number in format 5.5.12.1. I know that installer only works with first three numbers from version so MajorUpgrade is not suitable for me. New version would not be installed in this case. Is there a way in which I can check versions in some custom action and plan upgrade from there? I cannot change the versioning as app building goes through some automatic post-processes that also works only with first three numbers and it is not possible to change that behavior.

Thanks for suggestions.

EDIT:
I am using WiX#.

Comment: AFAIK wix is using windows version comparison methods. They rely on the first three numbers to detect an upgrade. Maybe you can create a bootstrapper module that deinstalls the old version before installing the newer one.

Comment: Do you have control over the invocation parameters used during installation?

Comment: Nope, but I am using WiX#

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious to me why you can't use the WiX majorupgrade element. The settings would be AllowDowngrades=yes, maybe AllowSameVersionUpgrades=yes.

Using Schedule=afterInstallValidate is (as the docs say) removes the old product entirely before installing the new upgrade.

Comment: I don't want to allow downgrades. Example in question doesn't work with MajorUpgrade as it would perform the downgrade instead of upgrade that I need. Problem is in my versioning schema as I need to check last (fourth) part for upgrade. MajorUpgrade uses only first three parts.

Comment: By definition, if you are going from 5.5.789 to 5.5.12 you are doing a downgrade, and allowdowngrades is how you say that. It seems that your definition of "upgrade" is "created after the other one" but that's not the way that Windows Installer defines it.